# Laravel Eloquent where in relationship may or may not have result

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, relational-database

I've got this relation:

A `Company` may have one or more `Employees`.

I need to `SELECT` Companies based on the `first_name` of an `Employee`, but not show it when the `first_name` of the employee doesn't match.

This is what I currently have.

```
$companies = Company::with(array('employees' => function($q) {
    $type = (!empty(Input::get('company_search_employee'))) ? '%' . Input::get('company_search_employee') . '%' : '%';
    $q->where( 'employees.first_name', 'LIKE', $type);
}))->get();
```

The employee `first_name` must be neglected if the `Company` doesn't have any `Employee`s

But it shows the Company data, even if the employee doesn't match. the employee just gets hidden.

How would I go on doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that way:

```
$companies = Company::whereHas('employees', function($q){
    $type = (!empty(Input::get('company_search_employee'))) ? '%' . Input::get('company_search_employee') . '%' : '%';
    $q->where( 'first_name', 'LIKE', $type);
})->get();
```

or if it doesnt work add 'employees' to where clause:

```
$q->where('employees.first_name', 'LIKE', $type);
```